# Remove word from a line - Bash

Tags: bash, url, removeall

I want to remove the `&amp;` from all the line

```
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=1
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=2
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=11
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=10
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=6
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=4
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=14
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=5
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=3
?daypartId=1&amp;catId=8
```

Expected output:

```
?daypartId=1&catId=1
?daypartId=1&catId=2
?daypartId=1&catId=11
?daypartId=1&catId=10
?daypartId=1&catId=6
?daypartId=1&catId=4
?daypartId=1&catId=14
?daypartId=1&catId=5
?daypartId=1&catId=3
?daypartId=1&catId=8
```

removing `&amp;` from the input is what i need. I am stuck at this problem please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do simply with sed like below:

```
sed 's/amp;//' myfile.txt
```

This would search for `amp;` and replace it with an empty string in a file called `myfile.txt`

If you want to replace it within the file, then you could use -i option as below:

```
sed -i 's/amp;//' myfile.txt
```

If you have multiple such occurrences in a line, you could use a global replacement as below:

```
sed 's/amp;//g' myfile.txt
```

Comment: I don't want an empty string. I want to remove `amp;` and combine the line like `?daypartId=1&catId=1` basically without `amp;`

Comment: @wahaj did you tried above command? That's exactly what it would do.